# Foundation 4 + Orbit Slider: Can't control animation speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am using Foundation to create a website that involves the Orbit Slider. Try as I may, I can't change the speed of the slider. Everything is working properly (jquery, slider controls, slider bullets, customized CSS for slider, etc.), I just can't seem to change the parameters of the slideshow.

The head of my document:

```
<script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).foundation('orbit', {
timer_speed: 100,
});
</script>
```

And at the end of my body:

```
  <script>
  document.write('<script src=js/vendor/' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>

  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation(
            );
  </script>
```

Like I said everything is functioning fine, I just can't change the parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using orbit before you have the foundation js loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below structure instead. Your issue is that you're referencing orbit before the foundation script is loaded, so that js in the head is essentially ignored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- your content -->


    <script>
      document.write('<script src=js/vendor/' +
      ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
      '.js><\/script>')
  </script>

  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation('orbit', {
        timer_speed: 100,
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```